# emacs eshell grep on grep output

Tags: emacs, grep, eshell

In eshell, one of the nice things is commands like grep's output will be redirected to Emacs special buffers. However, if I do a grep on previous grep, e.g.:

```
grep "abc" *.el | grep -v "ghi"
```

that output only appears in standard output. I'm wondering if there is a way to direct that output to Emacs special buffer as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(grep "grep abc *.el | grep -v ghi -")` opens the resulting matches in a new widow, but `next-error` does not work with it though.

Comment: Is the "grep a typo? I tried `(grep grep "raise" *.py | grep -v "RF_Test")`, `(grep 'grep "raise" *.py | grep -v "RF_Test")`, `(grep "grep" "raise" *.py | grep -v "RF_Test")` none of them works

Comment: @sudo sorry, the typo was when I pasted from the question, I did not remove the " marks.  Edited the answer.  Using 'abc' and 'ghi' works, if quoting is needed.

Comment: Ha, it's work now. Thanks. In order for it to really work well, I have to add -n : `(grep "grep -n abc *.el | grep -v ghi -")`